Solving the functional equation $f(x)=\frac4{(x+4)^2}f(\frac x{x+4})+2f(2x+1)$
Consider the functional equation
$$f(x)=\frac4{(x+4)^2}\,f\!\left(\frac x{x+4}\right)+2f(2x+1),\quad x\geq0.$$
I believe that there should be a unique non-identically-zero solution up to scaling. Empirically (iterating the equation until it converges), the function is continuous and decreasing.
How can I go about solving this explicitly? I tried writing the function as a Taylor series $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-1)^n$ and expanding, but the resulting equation
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\left(2^{n+1}a_n+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+n}}{4^{n+1}}\binom{k+n+1}na_k-\sum_{k=n}^\infty(-1)^{k-n}\binom kna_k\right)=0$$
doesn't yield any unique values for the $(a_n)$. Is there another method that can work here?
(This function arises as the fixed point of a certain transformation on a random variable.)
The empirical log-plot of $f(x)$ up to $x=100$, normalized to $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=1$:


Try elementary operations : look is it an even or odd function ? Why the creator of the exercise has put $x/(x+4)$ or $(2x+1)$ in this manner. Try to iterate/change variable $x$ can be replace by anything including a $x\to g(x)$ appropriate to find properties.

@EDX Even vs. odd makes no sense here, the definition is only valid for $x\geq0$. Also, this is no exercise: the question arose naturally from a different problem, and it was not specially designed to have any clever answer. I'm not sure what kind of iteration can help here, when the definition of $f(x)$ branches into an entire tree of independent $f$ values.

Yes after writing I saw your specific conditions which doesnt allows even or odd, but it doesn't make "non sense" , it can often be useful authorizing expansion on negative values and solve with symmetry yet, as with differential equation. I'm looking if we can have some interesting case.  Can you precise the context of your equation so ? Because otherwise, if it isn't an exercise, it may not have more explicit form that the series one. What encourages you to think it has ?

@EDX I'd be fine with a series form, the problem is that my current attempt hasn't worked for finding any coefficients. As for the full context, I have a sequence $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})=(x_n-y_n,4y_n+2)$ if $x_n>y_n$, $(2x_n+1,y_n-x_n)$ if $x_n<y_n$ (which further arises naturally), and I want to find the limiting factor $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}/x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_{n+1}/y_n\approx1.163$. To do this, I'm looking for the limiting distribution of $y_n/x_n$ ratios, of which $f(x)$ is the PDF.

I see. I will work with the inital context as well. What are the initial values ? Whar are conditions if $x_n=y_n$ ?

@EDX The process halts if $x_n=y_n$, but heuristically that will never happen for most $(x_0,y_0)$. But the average ratio doesn't depend on $(x_0,y_0)$ at all, so I'm far more interested in this limiting case.

One solution (up to scaling) is $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+3)}$

@Sil Thank you! It resembles my empirical solution precisely, so it's most likely the solution I'm looking for. I'd really appreciate if you could write up the process you used to solve it.

I expected it in form $1/(ax^2+bx+c)$ and solved for coefficients, nothing profound. I don't know if it is the only solution... If the uniqueness is not required I will summarize it in answer.

@Sil Go ahead, I've double-checked and found that your particular solution produces the results I wanted.

Can you explained how you can your first functionnal equation and what is a PDF for a sequence of vector ?

@EDX Take, e.g., $(x_0,y_0)=(1,2)$ and run it for a few thousand iterations: you'll find that both variables tend to increase exponentially at the same rate. In the limit, the constant terms become negligible, so we can model it as $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})=(x_n-y_n,4y_n)\text{ or }(2x_n,y_n-x_n)$. Rewrite this new iteration in terms of $(x_n,r_n),r_n=y_n/x_n$, and you'll find that $r_{n+1}$ is independent of $x_n$. Use the formula for the PDF of a transformed random variable (using $r_{n+1}=T(r_n)$), and you obtain the functional equation in the question.

Ok thanks  for precision !

Looking at a similar problem in this AoPS thread, it seems reasonable to expect the solution in a form $f(x)=\frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}$ for some $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$. Substituting this to the equation and solving for $a,b,c$ (for example, by choosing three values of $x$ to get a system of three equations in three variables), we get a solution
$$
f(x)=\frac{a}{(x+1)(x+3)}.
$$
(I suggest using a CAS system to save time). We can easily verify this is indeed a solution by substituting it back to the original equation. Whether it is the only one (up to the scaling constant $a$, of course), I do not know.
